# Drools 'variance' accumulate (Optaplanner scoring)

Tags: drools, optaplanner, accumulate

I am trying to distribute requests fairly to employees in Optaplanner (based on complexity of requests).So I want a rule to minimize the standard deviation of the complexity of requests assigned to an employee. 
I have tried writing a rule based on the Optaplanner documents,

```
rule "fairAssignment"
salience 1
    when
        $employee : Employee($possType: possibleProblemTypes, $availableTime: availableTime)
        $complexityTotal: Number() from accumulate
                            (Request(employee==$employee,problemType memberOf $possType,$Complexity :     complexity),sum(complexity))
    then
        scoreHolder.addSoftConstraintMatch(kcontext, -($complexityTotal.intValue()*     $complexityTotal.intValue()));

end
```

But I would prefer a solution, where [the standard deviation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation) is being minimized. So can you help me write an inline accumulate function for 'variance' ?

Comment: My gut instinct is to go with one rule to calculate the standard deviance which `insertLogical()` it, and then another rule with a lower salience for every employee to add the difference with the standard deviance as a negative soft constraint match.